How to set the default path for a DocumentGroup application in SwiftUI
I got a SwiftUI App where the main entry point is a DocumentGroup control.
This would show a file browser when the app starts.
Is there any reliable way how to configure the path where this file browser starts on open?
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(
            newDocument: createDocument() // create a new document..
        ) { configuration in
            ContentView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

What I did so far is calling FileManager.default.changeToDocumentsDircetory() on init of the App, the method changeToDocumentsDircetory is below:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    init() {
        FileManager.default.changeToDocumentsDircetory()
    }

    // .. the code from above
}

public extension FileManager {
    func documentsDirectory() -> URL {
        return self.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    }
    
    func createDocumentsDirectory() {
        let url = self.documentsDirectory()
        let path = url.path(percentEncoded: false)
        if !self.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            do {
                try self.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
            } catch {
                print("Cannot create the app document directory: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func changeToDocumentsDircetory() {
        self.createDocumentsDirectory()
        self.changeCurrentDirectoryPath(self.documentsDirectory().path(percentEncoded: false))
    }
}

So in essence I call changeCurrentDirectoryPath on the default FileManager.
But this works only partially, that means on some devices I see the right folder on the Phone is opened, on other devices I see the same but the iCloud "version" of the folder, not the one on the phone is opened.
